# Creating a custom XBL control in Orbeon for an HTML5 image map

Tags: orbeon

I have created a custom XBL control which contains an image and a map element (both in xhtml namespace) to define clickable areas.  I have been able to link up click events to set a checkbox but this only seems to work for one check/uncheck cycle.

Also, when I place another instance of the XBL on the form, the bound events for each control are not independent. eg clicking an area on one control sets a checkbox on the other!

I am trying to achieve something like this example http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html  but using an image to mark the selection instead of shading.

Do you think this would be possible to implement as a custom control in Orbeon?

Alternatively, a method to integrate the above imagemapster jquery plugin would be great too. I have tried but it doesn't seem to initialise correctly.

Thanks in advance, Jake.

Answer (score 0):

Yes absolutely, this is possible. There shouldn't be any limitations to what you can do, really. See in particular [JavaScript Companion Classes](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xbl/javascript.html) for JavaScript integration. Feel free to post specific questions separately,

Comment: Thanks, that's good news! Currently I am using jQuery to handle the events on the area tags which use the xhtml namespace. Should I dispatch these to the component and handle these internally as custom events?

Comment: If you need to handle these events on the XForms side, yes, you can dispatch events to the component. If you need these events only on the client-side, then you don't have to send them to the XForms side. Maybe some examples might help, like [`code-mirror.js`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/4d0caecc7e3892f3eb0a358d6f6e4e093b790418/src/main/assets/xbl/orbeon/code-mirror/code-mirror.js) or [`tabbable.js`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/4d0caecc7e3892f3eb0a358d6f6e4e093b790418/src/main/assets/xbl/orbeon/tabbable/tabbable.js).

Comment: Thanks for these examples.  Another issue I am having is binding click events to xhtml elements within the component.  What is the best way to do this so that the bind is kept independent from another instance of the control?

Comment: It depends what you would like to do with the handler. One way, using jQuery, is to register a single event handler for all instances of the control.

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution using event namespaces, so I can bind to a click event like  `click.control-name.unique_id`.   I also took the `var companion = this` from your examples to prevent conflicts using this.

Answer (score 0):

ODK now has a nice implementation, using SVG to replace selects: https://github.com/opendatakit/xforms-spec/issues/108

It'd be great to see something similar out-of-the-box in Orbeon